# Модуль Mongoose выводит пустой массив

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

у меня возникла проблема с модулем **mongoose**, Nodejs. В базе данных и коллекции есть данные, но node мне возвращает  пустой массив. Что делать?

**Вот код:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const jop = async()=>{
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shop", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, dox)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(`connect db ${dox}`);
        }
    });
}
const ahiop = async (req, res)=>{
    const userScheme = new Schema({login: String, password: String}, {versionKey: false});
    const User = mongoose.model('admin', userScheme);
    const finder = await User.find({}).exec();
    console.log(finder);
};
jop().then(ahiop());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемой оказалось что я создавал коллекции в разных базах данных. Compass создавала базу в каком-то не ясном url с get запросом, в то время как node искала ссылку без get запросов. Решением оказалось чтобы убрать get запрос с mongoCompass, а также добавление в конце окончание -s (не ясно почему node могла обращаться лишь с окончанием -s).